# Unexpected Token Illegal for an array

Tags: jquery, arrays, token

I cannot figure out why I am getting an error from Chrome's Developer Tool.  The following line:

```
var accessoriesCats = [ “Beaded Accessories”, “Cufflinks”, “Flip Flops”, “Floral Accessories”, “Foot Jewelry”, “Hair Accessories”, “Hankies”, “Jewelry”, “Leg Garters”, “Purses”, “Shoe Stickers”, “Something Blue”, “Tiaras”, “Totes” ];
```

Comes up with the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL.

I'm not sure if it is indeed this line that is the problem, or something else.

Here is the entire code:

```
<script>
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("category-s/2022.htm") != -1) {
            var accessoriesCats = [ “Beaded Accessories”, “Cufflinks”, “Flip Flops”, “Floral Accessories”, “Foot Jewelry”, “Hair Accessories”, “Hankies”, “Jewelry”, “Leg Garters”, “Purses”, “Shoe Stickers”, “Something Blue”, “Tiaras”, “Totes” ];
                $('#content_area > table:nth-child(6) > tbody > tr > td > table:nth-child(1) > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody').find('a').each(accessoriesCats, function(){
                            $(this).append('<span class="promo__text”>”+accessoriesCats+”</span>');
                            $(this).removeClass('smalltext colors_text').addClass('subcatRollover');
            });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Those aren't normal quotes... they're fancy... `“ != "`

Answer (score 2):

You have used bad quotes, use `"` or `'` instead of `“` and `”`:

```
var accessoriesCats = [ "Beaded Accessories", "Cufflinks", "Flip Flops", "Floral Accessories", "Foot Jewelry", "Hair Accessories", "Hankies", "Jewelry", "Leg Garters", "Purses", "Shoe Stickers", "Something Blue", "Tiaras", "Totes" ];
```

Answer (score 1):

Its your quotes, `“”` those are a different unicode version so they're not recognized by the complier. You need `""` or `''`:

Try this instead:

```
var accessoriesCats = [ 'Beaded Accessories', 'Cufflinks', 'Flip Flops', 'Floral Accessories', 'Foot Jewelry', 'Hair Accessories', 'Hankies', 'Jewelry', 'Leg Garters', 'Purses', 'Shoe Stickers', 'Something Blue', 'Tiaras', 'Totes' ];
```